# Python, zip multiple lists where one list requires two items each

Tags: python, list

I have the following lists as an example:

```
a = ['#12908069', '#12906115', '#12904949', '#12904654', '#12904288', '#12903553']    
b = ['85028,', '83646,', '77015,', '90011,', '91902,', '80203,']    
c = ['9.09', '9.09', '1.81', '3.62', '1.81', '1.81', '9.09', '9.09', '1.81', '3.62', '1.81', '1.81']    
d = ['Zone 3', 'Zone 3', 'Zone 2']
```

What I'd like to achieve as an output, the first item set zipped as an example:

```
[('#12908069', '85028', (9.09, 9.09), 'Zone 3'), ...]
```

How do I get `zip()` to add an extra item for each tuple from list `c`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use list slices with a step of 2, see [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1176601):

```
list(zip(a,b,zip(c[0::2],c[1::2]),d))
```

Answer (score 6):

using *an idiom for clustering a data series into n-length groups* from the [zip documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> gr = [iter(c)]*2
>>> list(zip(a, b, zip(*gr), d))
[('#12908069', '85028,', ('9.09', '9.09'), 'Zone 3'),
 ('#12906115', '83646,', ('1.81', '3.62'), 'Zone 3'),
 ('#12904949', '77015,', ('1.81', '1.81'), 'Zone 2')]
```

essentially, in order to get two consecutive elements from list `c` we put the same iterator on it in the `gr` list, which is made of two elements.

Then we pass those same iterators to zip (unpacking the list, as if we had passed the two iterators as two separate arguments to it).

That has the effect of collecting each two consecutive elements from list `c`.

We then pass such zip and the other lists to zip again to scan and pair the whole lot.

Comment: this is clever, but very un-maintainable IMO, I had to wrap my head around 2 copies of a reference to the same iterator

Comment: @Aprillion such idiom is quite common for clustering a data series into n-length groups

Comment: hmm, looks like it's been added to the documentation - https://bugs.python.org/issue23695 - I will just have to get used to it :)

Comment: @Aprillion BTW, note how it does not create any new list (at least in python 3), whereas slicing does.

Answer (score 3):

Using one of the [recipes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> 
>>> def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
...     "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
...     # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
...     args = [iter(iterable)] * n
...     return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
... 
>>> list(zip(a, b, grouper(c, 2), d))
[('#12908069', '85028,', ('9.09', '9.09'), 'Zone 3'), ('#12906115', '83646,', ('1.81', '3.62'), 'Zone 3'), ('#12904949', '77015,', ('1.81', '1.81'), 'Zone 2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
a = ['#12908069', '#12906115', '#12904949', '#12904654', '#12904288', '#12903553']
b = ['85028,', '83646,', '77015,', '90011,', '91902,', '80203,']
c = ['9.09', '9.09', '1.81', '3.62', '1.81', '1.81', '9.09', '9.09', '1.81', '3.62', '1.81', '1.81']
d = ['Zone 3', 'Zone 3', 'Zone 2']

result = list(zip(a, b, [(c[i*2],c[i*2+1]) for i in range(len(c)//2)], d))
print(result)
```

Comment: `result = list(zip(...` will do. No need for `i,j,m,n`